# Mongo socketTimeoutMS doesn't work

Tags: php, mongodb

I perform "findOne()" query from PHP 5.4 to Mongo 2.4.10
PHP mongo driver version is 1.5.5
Mongo DB is replicaset

To limit waiting for results of this "findOne()" query I use "socketTimeoutMS" option
According to documentation in case of exceeding "socketTimeoutMS" function "findOne()" must throw "MongoCursorTimeoutException" exception
But I don't see any exception in logs

Also I measure excecution time of this "findOne()" query --- often it's more (sometimes in several times) than "socketTimeoutMS"

So looks like that "socketTimeoutMS" option doesn't work
Need to mention that our mongo DB is under very high load

Also need to mention that on my local machine "socketTimeoutMS" works OK

So what can be reasons for "socketTimeoutMS" option ignorance on production ?

```
2 --- 4   Using 50 from default with
2 --- 4   found connection 192.168.2.172:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843 (looking for 192.168.2.172:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843)
2 --- 4   is_ping: skipping: last ran at 1407943807, now: 1407943807, time left: 5
2 --- 4   found connection 192.168.2.92:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843 (looking for 192.168.2.92:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843)
2 --- 4   is_ping: skipping: last ran at 1407943807, now: 1407943807, time left: 5
2 --- 4   found connection 192.168.2.94:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843 (looking for 192.168.2.94:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843)
2 --- 4   is_ping: skipping: last ran at 1407943807, now: 1407943807, time left: 5
2 --- 4   discover_topology: checking ismaster for 192.168.2.172:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843
2 --- 4   discover_topology: checking ismaster for 192.168.2.92:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843
2 --- 4   found connection 192.168.2.92:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843 (looking for 192.168.2.92:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843)
2 --- 4   ismaster: skipping: last ran at 1407943798, now: 1407943807, time left: 6
2 --- 4   discover_topology: ismaster got skipped
2 --- 4   discover_topology: checking ismaster for 192.168.2.94:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843
2 --- 4   found connection 192.168.2.94:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843 (looking for 192.168.2.94:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843)
2 --- 4   ismaster: skipping: last ran at 1407943798, now: 1407943807, time left: 6
2 --- 4   discover_topology: ismaster got skipped
2 --- 4   No timeout changes for 192.168.2.92:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843
2 --- 4   No timeout changes for 192.168.2.92:27017;gmt;admin/gmt/fb5f987e48d27c093e233d3cda7758e2;11843
```

Comment: What does [MongoLog](http://php.net/mongolog) report? You should be able to log the timeout settings that get applied by calling  `MongoLog::setLevel(MongoLog::FINE)` and `MongoLog::setModule(MongoLog::CON)` earlier in the script. By the way, I noticed that the documentation for these constants was a bit outdated, as `CON` isn't documented. I created [PHP-1162](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-1162) as a reminder to fix that.

Comment: Thank for advise I enabled MongoLog But what should I see in log in case of of exceeding "socketTimeoutMS" ?

Comment: There should be `CON` module messages at the `FINE` level detailing the stream timeout that is applied. Additionally, you'll likely see "No timeout changes" for queries where you don't override `socketTimeoutMS` (i.e. the MongoClient option is used). If `socketTimeoutMS` is being ignored for you, does that mean `findOne()` is actually returning the query result?

Comment: I'll also note that `socketTimeoutMS` is a poor tool for reducing server query load, as it only controls the client-side timeout. A long-running query will remain active on the server. To reduce server query time, you should consider [MongoCursor::maxTimeMS()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.maxtimems.php), which sets the [`$maxTimeMS`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxTimeMS/) query operator; however, that operator is only available in MongoDB 2.6+.

Comment: Thanks for advices Added MongoLog info to question description           Also need to note that I already use **$maxTimeMS**

Comment: Based on the logs, it looks as if the stream IO is definitely using a 50ms client-side timeout. At this point, it'd probably be worth including a standalone PHP script that reproduces the problem on production (but not on your local environment). Including how you calculate the execution timing (which you say is exceeding socketTimeoutMS) would also be helpful.